# Scala compiler error: "identifier expected but integer literal found". Why?

Tags: scala

The code is obvious, and I fail to see what's wrong with it.

```
object TestX extends App {

  val l= List[String]( "a","b","c" )
  val n= l.size

  def f( i:Int )= l[(i+1)%n ]
}
```

Compiler output (Scala 2.9.2):

```
  fsc -deprecation -d bin src/xxx.scala
  src/xxx.scala:11: error: identifier expected but integer literal found.
    def f( i:Int )= l[(i+1)%n]
                         ^
```

Comment: Leaving this here (though it's such a simple one!) because the title may lead someone else to find the cure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Brackets `[`, `]` in Scala are used to declare or apply *type parameters*. Getting an element in a sequence or array is the `apply(index: Int)` method where `apply` may be omitted. Thus:

```
def f(i:Int) = l.apply((i + 1) % n)
```

or short

```
def f(i:Int) = l((i + 1) % n)
```

---

Note that `apply` and `size` on a `List` take time O(N), so if you need those operations often for large lists, consider using `Vector` instead.

Comment: Hurray! Yes, I know that. :) Yes, this was the first bite on this particular. Thanks!!!